# Setting specific tile size for geom_tile between two graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2

Might be missing something simple here, but my goal is to plot two heatmaps from two separate matrices. The matrices are of different dimensions, but I want each of the individual plotted tiles to be the same physical measurements between the two graphs. The graph size should then be dependent on the matrix dimensions, since the tile size will be constant between the graphs.

Here is an example of two different size matrices and a stripped down version of the graphs I want to make.

```
mat_lg <- matrix(rexp(20, rate=.1), ncol = 5)

melt(mat_lg) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_equal()

mat_sm <- matrix(rexp(12, rate = .1), ncol = 3)

melt(mat_sm) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_equal()
```

The graph made from mat_lg has smaller tiles...
[image]

compared to the tiles in the graph made from mat_sm...
[image]

I've played around with the width/height settings in geom_tile, but was unable to achieve my goal. Have also played with grid.arrange as well as facet_wrap settings but to no avail.

My guess is that I need to change the final plot size based on my initial matrix dimension in order to get the tiles with the same physical measurements. Would gladly appreciate any help on this matter!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the two matrices have at least one dimension that is equal, then this is accomplished directly by `egg::ggarrange()`, which lines up the plot panels:

```
## Save plots into variables
gg1 <- melt(mat_lg) %>% ggplot(...)
gg2 <- melt(mat_sm) %>% ggplot(...)

## Let ggarrange line up the panels
egg::ggarrange( gg1, gg2 )
```

[image]

If dimensions of the two matrices differ entirely, use `egg::set_panel_size` to adjust the panel sizes explicitly:

```
p1 <- egg::set_panel_size( gg1, height=unit(ncol(mat_lg), "cm"),
                          width=unit(nrow(mat_lg), "cm") )
p2 <- egg::set_panel_size( gg2, height=unit(ncol(mat_sm), "cm"),
                          width=unit(nrow(mat_sm), "cm") )
cowplot::plot_grid( p1, p2, nrow=1 )
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, the `set_panel_size` was just what I was looking for. Thanks! Will award bounty to you after the initial period is done.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you want that both your heatmap as the same heigh and width. 
Based on your example, you should calculate the ratio between your matrices and passed it as argument in `coord_equal`. On your example, it should look like:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
mat_lg <- matrix(rexp(20, rate=.1), ncol = 5)

melt(mat_lg) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_equal()

mat_sm <- matrix(rexp(12, rate = .1), ncol = 3)
scale_factor = ncol(mat_lg) / ncol(mat_sm)

melt(mat_sm) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_equal(ratio = scale_factor)
```

And you get both heatmaps at the same size:

mat_sm:

[image]

mat_lg:

[image]

Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: Not quite - I am looking for each tile to be the same physical size. It is okay for the final plot dimensions to be of different sizes, as long as the tile size between the two graphs is the same. I'll edit my question to clarify.

Comment: Ok, sorry I did not understand your question the first time. Now, it's clearer thanks ! If I think about something that could help you, I will let you know.