# R shiny ggplot2 heatmap: uniform size of plots and align left

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, shiny, heatmap

In my shiny app I filter the heatmaps with a selectinput to show them in tab1.
Everything is working fine. But, I have tried to get a uniform size a.) of the different heatmaps (all should have the same overall size and all should have same tile size), and b.) to align the heatmaps on the left side (actually it is centered).
I am not able to get behind the issue, although I went through the online explanations. Thanks for your help.

My code:

global.R

```
# global.R
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# construct the dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  test_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
              3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
  test_nr = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
              1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  region = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", 
             "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", 
             "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D"),
  test_value = c(3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 
                 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 99, 99, 3, 3, 3, 3)
)

# named vector for heatmap
cols <-  c("1" = "green", 
           "2" = "darkgreen", 
           "3" = "orange", 
           "4" = "red",
           "99" = "black")
labels_legend <- c("1" = "Complete response", 
                   "2" = "Major response", 
                   "3" = "Minor response", 
                   "4" = "No response", 
                   "99" = "NA")
```

ui.R

```
# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML("
    .tabbable > .nav > li > a {background-color: aqua;  color:black; width: 300PX;}
  ")),
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("TEST HEATMAP"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(width = 2,
                 # Input: Select the id ----
                 selectInput(inputId = "test_id", 
                             label = "Test ID", 
                             choices = df$test_id,
                             selected = NULL)
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(width = 10,
              
              # Output: Tabset plot,  ----
              tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                          tabPanel("tab1",
                                   plotOutput("test_plot")
                          ),
                          tabPanel("tab2",
                                   ),
                          tabPanel("tab3", 
                                   )
                          )
              )  
    )
  )
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  var_testid <- reactive({input$test_id})
  
  output$test_plot <- renderPlot({
    
    req(var_testid())

    df <- df %>% 
      filter(test_id == as.integer(var_testid())) # filter testid
    
    
    ggplot(
      df, 
      aes(region, test_nr)) +
      geom_tile(aes(fill= factor (test_value))) +
      geom_text(aes(label = test_value), size = 10, color = "white") + # text in tiles
      scale_colour_manual(
        values = cols, 
        breaks = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "99"),
        labels = labels_legend,
        aesthetics = c("colour", "fill")
      ) +
      theme(text = element_text(size = 14)) + # this will change all text size
      labs(title =  "Test (Individual heatmap)", x = "Region", y = "Event") +
      labs(fill = "Test") +
      coord_fixed(ratio=1, clip="on") +
      theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12)) +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, face = "bold", size = 12)) +
      theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "darkblue", 
                                     size = 1, linetype = "solid")
      )
  })
  
})
```

Comment: If you comment out the line `coord_fixed()`, you get all heatmaps to be of same overall size and aligned to the left.

Comment: Thank you YBS. Combining with fluidRow() and column() in the ui section I am happy.

Comment: How can I implement the solution given here by Artem Sokolov: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830318/setting-specific-tile-size-for-geom-tile-between-two-graphs> in my example code above. where the tiles of a ggplot2 heatmap have the same size. 

So the difference is that the heatmaps change when clicking the shiny selectInput widget. 
How can I apply egg::ggarrange( gg1, gg2 ) for my reactive shiny solution. 
Thanks in advance.